# How to get total area covered while drawing path on canvas android?

Tags: android, draw, android-canvas

Im using below code to draw  line on bitmap canvas while finger touch move... here i posted partial code and it is working fine..

As shown in below image, the black and white bitmap erased on touch drag.. I made canvas transparent so the parent layout background(color image) is getting visible.

I want to know , how much area is erased(like 50% or 60% of bitmap ).. is there any way to find that?

[image]

```
//Erasing paint

         mDrawPaint = new Paint();
    mDrawPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 
    mDrawPaint.setDither(true);  
    mDrawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
    mDrawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mDrawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mDrawPaint.setStrokeWidth(50); 
    mDrawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    BlurMaskFilter mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    mDrawPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
```

---

```
private void doDraw(Canvas c) {

    c.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0,null );

}
```

---

```
private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 1;

void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

     canvas.drawPath(mPath, mDrawPaint ); //Erasing Black and white image

}
void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mDrawPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}
```

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you would have to check every single pixel of mBitmap and see if it is blank.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [Monte Carlo method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to estimate percentage of transparent area. I think it is a fastest and easiest  way to do this. Take about 50 (depends on accuracy you need) random pixels on your transparency mask and check their color. Then calc ans = TransparentPixelsCount/TestPixelCount.

It is very hard to calculate square of user's drawings using path coordinates. And it's quite long to iterate over all pixels. So, IMHO Monte Carlo is your choise.

Comment: Could you please share an implemented sample on android/java?

Answer (score 5):

To get an exact (and slow) answer, you need to inspect every pixel and count the number are transparent and divide by the total number of pixels.  If your requirements allow for some estimation, it is probably best to sample the image.

You could downsize the image and run and the above procedure on the smaller image.  That has the disadvantage that the scaling operation might be going through all the pixels making it slow.  I would recommend a grid sampling, it is similar to downsizing, but skips over pixels. Basically, we evenly space x sample points on a grid over the image.  Then count the number of sample points that are transparent.  The estimate of transparent percentage is the total transparent samples/number of transparent samples.  You can get reasonable accuracy (usually within 5%) with a small number, say 100, samples.  Here is a code function that implements this method -- bm is the `Bitmap` and `scale` is the number of samples per axis, so setting `scale = 10` gives 100 total samples (10x10 sampling grid over the image).

```
static public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm, int scale) {

        final int width = bm.getWidth();
        final int height = bm.getHeight();

        // size of sample rectangles
        final int xStep = width/scale;
        final int yStep = height/scale;

        // center of the first rectangle
        final int xInit = xStep/2;
        final int yInit = yStep/2;

        // center of the last rectangle
        final int xEnd = width - xStep/2;
        final int yEnd = height - yStep/2;

        int totalTransparent = 0;

        for(int x = xInit; x <= xEnd; x += xStep) {
            for(int y = yInit; y <= yEnd; y += yStep) {
                if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    totalTransparent++;
                }
            }
        }
        return ((float)totalTransparent)/(scale * scale);

    }
```

For reference, the slow method that would give you the results by counting every pixel is below.  It can be used for reference on testing the above estimator.

```
static public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm) {
        final int width = bm.getWidth();
        final int height = bm.getHeight();

        int totalTransparent = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    totalTransparent++;
                }
            }
        }
        return ((float)totalTransparent)/(width * height);

    }
```

Comment: if the bitmap size is equal to device size then wht is the scale i have to give?

Comment: It is independent of the device size, it is how many samples you want to take.  More samples = better accuracy.  Scale 10 = 100 samples, so each one represents one percent of the image.  If you want better than that, you can try 15 or 20 (for 20, each sample is .25%). I tried it out with 640x480 images at `scale = 10`, and it was usually within 3-4% of the actual value.

Comment: @vnshetty. Forgot to include you on the previous comment, and I added the full solution to test the estimate against.

Comment: I tried your code but im getting like 0.7778E34 % values.. i called this function on on touch up.... however i want this to be done on touch move and tht would be even more hard when it comes to speed issue...

Comment: @vnshetty  What scale are you using?  As for speed, that is why you take smaller samples, the second routine is going to be painfully slow , but gives exact results.  First routine provides an estimate, but runs much quicker, especially for a small number of samples)

Comment: Hi I'm also using this same example. But everytime my percentage is getting 0%. That means `bm.getPixel(x, y)` always has a non-zero value. please help.Refer [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336113/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-erased-area-of-a-bitmap-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach on this: you can calculate the size of each path using [ComputeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#computeBounds%28android.graphics.RectF,%20boolean%29). Then it should be simple to compare this with the size of your view and decide the % of the drawing.

Jus you need to keep in mind that the path can be drawn over itself, so you need to be careful and handle that in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the points lying inside the drawn polygon.
Here is the functions which takes array that contains all the drawn point, and second parameter are the points itself i.e. x ,y.

```
// Return true if the dot { x,y } is within any of the polygons in the list

function pointInPolygons( polygons, dot )

      for (i=1, [polygons count] i++)
         {
           if (pointInPolygon( polygons[i], dot )) 
                    return true
         } 

      return false
end

// Returns true if the dot { x,y } is within the polygon 
//defined by points table { {x,y},-    --{x,y},{x,y},... }

function pointInPolygon( points, dot )
    local i, j = #points, #points
    local oddNodes = false

    for i=1, #points do
            if ((points[i].y < dot.y and points[j].y>=dot.y
                    or points[j].y< dot.y and points[i].y>=dot.y) and (points[i].x<=dot.x
                    or points[j].x<=dot.x)) then
                    if (points[i].x+(dot.y-points[i].y)/(points[j].y-points[i].y)*(points[j].x-points[i].x)<dot.x) then
                            oddNodes = not oddNodes
                    end
            end
            j = i
    end

    return oddNodes
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all point x and y value in two different sorted sets, one for x value of point and other for y value of point.
The final value of your bound will be point(min_x,min_y) and point(max_x,max_y).