# Android: How to get the area size of a drawn path?

Tags: java, android, area, geometry-path

My problem is to measure the surface area of a path. 
 I generate a random Path and draw it on a canvas. After touching on this closen path, i want to get the area size of this drawn path.

How can i get the real area size of this path?

The pathes (shapes) looks like this here:

[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uuRv.png)

Comment: don´t know exactly if its true, but if path is drawn with RectF, from this You should get the area size..

Comment: take a look at this similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357246/how-to-get-total-area-covered-while-drawing-path-on-canvas-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I generate a Region from the path and use a RegionIterator to get Rects inside the Region. With this Rects i can calculate the whole area of the path.

```
private void calculateArea(Region region) {

        RegionIterator regionIterator = new RegionIterator(region);

        int size = 0; // amount of Rects
        float area = 0; // units of area

        Rect tmpRect= new Rect(); 

        while (regionIterator.next(tmpRect)) {
            size++;
            area += tmpRect.width() * tmpRect.height();
        }

        log.d("Rect amount=" + size);
        log.d("Area Size / units of area=" + area);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you converted your path to a region?

Comment: @Anil this is how to convert path into region Region region1 = new Region(); RectF rectF1 = new RectF(); tpath.computeBounds(rectF1, true);  region1.setPath(tpath, new Region((int) rectF1.left, (int) rectF1.top, (int) rectF1.right, (int) rectF1.bottom));

Answer (score 0):

This shows simply how to convert path to rectangle.

```
RectF getAreaFromPath(Path sourcePath){
    RectF rectF = new RectF();
    sourcePath.computeBounds(rectF, true);

    //You can get width and height by calling rectF.width(), rectF.height()

    return rectF;
}
```