# Surface area of a Path2d enclosed shape

Tags: java, path, area

I need to determine the correct area within a properly inclosed Path2d (shape) which can contain curve segments, line segments etc.

The Area class deals with the union, subtractions etc, which (I'm surprised) doesn't provid you with the surface area of the complex shape.

Answer (score -1):

write your own methods and use them whenever you need them

for example :

---

the area of a **triangle** is equal to :

```
public double getArea() {
    double area = 0.0;
    double halfPerimeter = getPerimeter() ;
    area = Math.sqrt(halfPerimeter*(halfPerimeter-side[0])*
    (halfPerimeter-side[1])*(halfPerimeter-side[2])) ;
    return area;
}
```

---

and the area for the **circle** :

```
public double getArea() {
    double area = 0.0;
    area = (Math.PI * Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ));
    return area;
}
```

---

and so on ..

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which is how to find the area of a complex shape.

Comment: I think that for every shape -even complex ones - we have a way to get  its area mathematically and I showed two examples of 2D shapes just to clarify the point .

Comment: Thanks iShaalan. Correct me if I'm wrong - you are simply saying to distinguished each segment of a Path2d and then do the calculation for each segmented shape but VGR is correct because there can be overlapping areas (regions) within a complex shape. This is where your approach would fail.

Comment: my idea is that if the shape's area can be gotten mathematically then we can transfer it to a code ..it seems that I didn't get you question correctly .. sorry for that :)

Comment: No props - you are on the right track but your example only solve's a part of it. I'm just looking at solving this myself. My idea is to iterate through the Path2d with a PathIterator and apply methods like the ones you mention above after (this is the difficult part) identifying weather the curves within the Path2d are part of the complex shape area or not. This should allow for a final step where one can  add or subtract the curved area to the calculation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hope that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236451/android-how-to-get-the-area-size-of-a-drawn-path?rq=1