# Calculate Area Size of UIBezierPath Custom Shapes

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, geometry

I have UIBezierPathes like this:

[image: Shapes]

And I want to calculate the area size of this kind of custom shapes. I don't have any idea to manage this calculation for this complex shapes in Objective c. I found here something for Android but didn't found something similar for iOS: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236451/android-how-to-get-the-area-size-of-a-drawn-path?rq=1)

I dont need a working solution, just need an idea or some pseudo code to solve this problem if there is an way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your regions are surrounded by Bezier curves (including straight lines), then you can exploit Green's theorem for parametric curves ([formula 10 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html)) to find area of region. Just calculate value of integral for every curve of contour:

```
 A = Integral[t=0..1] (y(t)*x'(t)*dt)
```

for cubic Bezier curve, defined by control points P[]:

```
 A = Integral[0..1](y(t)*x'(t)*dt)=
     Integral[0..1](
            (P[0].Y*(1-t)^3+3*P[1].Y*t*(1-t)^2+3*P[2].Y*t^2*(1-t)+P[3].Y*t^3)*
            (P[0].X*(1-t)^3+3*P[1].X*t*(1-t)^2+3*P[2].X*t^2*(1-t)+P[3].X*t^3)' * dt)
```

We have to expand the brackets, differentiate the second line expression, multiply expressions, and integrate the result. Resulting formulas are rather large, but easy to implement. Maple work to derive formulas:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? Maybe give a quick example of how to implement that.

Comment: @smnk Variable like`P0Y` corresponds to `P[0].Y`  - y-component of the first control point of cubic Bezier curve. So picture shows almost ready-to-use code piece (simplification "by hands" is possible - for example, there are some repeating terms)