# Scratch image in android?

Tags: android, image

I want to show image only when user scratch on that, image will be overlay with colors. So when user scratch on it they can see the image. I will finished that part by using  [this link](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView).

But what i need is while user scratch on that image, progress bar want to  show the current progress.   if user scratches all the portion of image progress bar should finish 100%.

Comment: Try to add some more information. What did you try, what is you idea?

Comment: Wow.. you got some intresting stuff here.. can you put in more details ?

Comment: i try from this [link](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView)

Comment: I think this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14357246/27190.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Android-WScratchView](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView) library, you can register `OnScratchCallback` and assign the percentage of cleared part to your progressbar

```
scratchView.setOnScratchCallback(new WScratchView.OnScratchCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onScratch(float percentage) {

            yourProgressBar.setProgress(percentage);//Assign progressbar value here

        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach(boolean fingerDetach) {
            if(mPercentage > 50){
                scratchView.setScratchAll(true);
                updatePercentage(100);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can check full sample at [here](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView/blob/master/testWScratchView/src/com/winsontan520/testwscratchview/DefaultCodes.java)