# How to calculate the percentage of erased area of a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint, touch-event

I'm new to android. I'm doing an application which can erase the bitmap on canvas using finger. Something like finger paint eraser. I want to calculate the percentage of erased area (eg. 60% has been erased from complete image). Please help me to do this.. Thanks in advance..

I tried some method. It always give me 0%. Its not working. See the bottom of the code for that method..

Customized View

```
public class MyView extends View
{
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private final Path mPath;
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Bitmap eraseableBitmap;

    public MyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    protected void PaintObjectInit()
    {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        try
        {
            //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            eraseableBitmap =
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tharu_rena_over).copy(
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            eraseableBitmap = getResizedBitmap(eraseableBitmap, h, w);

            mCanvas = new Canvas(eraseableBitmap );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth)
    {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        //canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(eraseableBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y)
    {
        //        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y)
    {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
        {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up()
    {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted: " + percentTransparent(eraseableBitmap, 10), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static public float percentTransparent(Bitmap bm, int scale)
    {

        final int width = bm.getWidth();
        final int height = bm.getHeight();

        // size of sample rectangles
        final int xStep = width / scale;
        final int yStep = height / scale;

        // center of the first rectangle
        final int xInit = xStep / 2;
        final int yInit = yStep / 2;

        // center of the last rectangle
        final int xEnd = width - xStep / 2;
        final int yEnd = height - yStep / 2;

        int totalTransparent = 0;

        for (int x = xInit; x <= xEnd; x += xStep)
        {
            for (int y = yInit; y <= yEnd; y += yStep)
            {
                if (bm.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                {
                    totalTransparent++;
                }
            }
        }
        return ((float) totalTransparent) / (scale * scale);

    }

}
```

Inside Activity Class onCreate

```
try
{
    MyView myView = new MyView(this);
    myView.requestFocus();
    myView.PaintObjectInit();
    // setContentView(myView);

    LinearLayout upper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
    upper.addView(myView);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work but why don't you just debug your function and see if all your variables are correct like `xStep` or try the function with steps of 1 pixel and check if it even comes in the for loop, and if so you can Log the `bm.getPixel(x, y)`. you can then probably work out yourself why it doesn't work

Comment: Thnx, I debugged. It goes inside the loop. And always bm.getPixel(x, y) is non zero. Since I gave it  scale 10, each time it iterates 100 times. so I went through about 20 iterations. For all those pixels I got a non zero value. And always it toast 0.0 % deleted. I dont know why.

Comment: where are you setting "erased" pixels to Color.TRANSPARENT?

Comment: When touching, it will make the the pixels Color.TRANSPARENT along the path right.? I think all the pixels that covers draw path will set to Color.TRANSPARENT. I got that code from finger paint sample application from sdk.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate percentage of erased area? Please share! Thanks.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh in my question you can see percentTransparent(Bitmap bm, int scale) method. It calculates the percentage. as you can see you have to pass the perticular bitmap with scale(to divide bitmap into samples) Just go through the code you can understand it. I screwed it up where I'm re sizing the bitmap. Unless code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are failing to call your `PaintObjectInit()` method, so you are painting with a default paint, so painting in `Color.BLACK` instead of `Color.TRANSPARENT`.  Add a call to `PaintObjectInit()` at the bottom of you constructor and it should work.

Also, the following creates an immutable bitmap! See [`createBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29). So, your bitmap is never being modified.  You are hiding this fact on the user interface by drawing the path as well as the bitmap.

```
// "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
return resizedBitmap;
```

Try making a mutable bitmap like this --

```
// "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);
        c.setMatrix(matrix);
        c.drawBitmap(bm, matrix, null);
        return resizedBitmap;
```

Comment: Nope. I'm calling it inside my activity class, before adding that view object to the layout. So my erasing part is working.

Comment: How are you calling `PaintObjectInit()` from the activity class if it is a protected method of your view?  Are you make any other changes to the state of your object from outside this code?

Comment: it is probably best to have the view initialize itself, so this step is do any time you reuse the view.  It is something easy to forget, and when I copied your code made for an obvious trouble.  The root of your error is a immutable bitmap that you allocate in your `getResizedBitmap` method. Edited answer.

Comment: Now I have an another issue. Now pixels are getting transparent. But when I draw line its getting duplicated.(two lines are drawn) And when I touched the above area in image. bottom area is also getting deleted. I guess there are now 2 bitmaps. And which I have expanded using matrix (as your answer) its only stretches the image without changing the width and height in original bitmap(what I actually want from that method). please help me to sort this. Thank you.